Задача по графам
Условия:
Дан массив из целых чисел (-100 000 000 ≤ arr[i] ≤ 100 000 000).

Можно перемещаться по массиву вперед и назад на один шаг (i - 1 или i + 1).

Также можно перемещаться по массиву по одинаковым числам в любом направлении за один шаг.


Задача найти минимальное число шагов от первого числа к последнему.
На вход подаётся строка, содержащая массив целых чисел длинной n (1 ≤ n ≤ 50 000)
Пример 1
Ввод: 4 6 3 3 6
Вывод: 2
Объяснение: С первого числа(4) можно попасть только на второе(6).
Со второго(6) можно переместиться на пятое(6), так как числа одинаковые.
Минимальное количество шагов: 2.
Пример 2
Ввод: 31 -6 -6 21 31 8 8 8 5 21
Вывод: 3
Объяснение: С первого(31) перемещаемся на пятое(31), шаг назад до четвертого(21), потом до последнего(21).
Пример 3
Ввод: 7 6 1 6 1 6 1 7
Вывод: 1
Объяснение: С первого(7) перемещаемся на последнее(7).
МОЁ РЕШЕНИЕ:
Решаю через граф.
Числа - вершины. Вес ребер считаю за единицу.
Использовал обход в ширину предварительно удалив дубликаты подряд идущих элементов, но песочница не принимает, из-за превышения лимита времени выполнения.
Может кто помочь?
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = Arrays.stream(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" "))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == arr.length - 1) {
                list.add(arr[i]);
            } else {
                if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
                    list.add(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (list.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println(0);
            return;
        }
        if (list.size() == 2) {
            System.out.println(1);
            return;
        }

        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            if (i == 0) {
                set.add(i + 1);
            } else if (i == list.size() - 1) {
                set.add(i - 1);
            } else {
                set.add(i - 1);
                set.add(i + 1);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (j != i && list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) {
                    set.add(j);
                }
            }
            map.put(i, set);
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        queue.add(0);
        distances.put(0, 0);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Integer current = queue.poll();
            if (current == list.size() - 1) break;
            for (Integer neighbor : map.get(current)) {
                Integer newDist = distances.get(current) + 1;
                if (newDist < distances.getOrDefault(neighbor, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                    distances.put(neighbor, newDist);
                    queue.add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(distances.get(list.size() - 1));

    }
}


В связанном вопросе "Задача о перемещении между островами" в комментариях описаны другие подходы к решению этой задачи.

@StanislavVolodarskiy  Спасибо за ваш ответ! Я и правда использую поиск в ширину. Вместо visited у меня проверка дистанции: если в мапе лежит дистанция и она меньше, то пропускаем. Но пробовал и с visited. После удаления повторяющихся дубликатов алгоритм заметно ускорился, но этого все-равно не хватает.

@NowhereMan Спасибо за ваш ответ! Упомянутый вами вопрос видел, что и побудило меня задать мой. В комментариях к нему не нашел ни одного подхода, который смог бы осмысленно применить. Если бы вы могли подсказать, какой подход предпочли бы вы - буду очень благодарен. Хотел бы добавить, что в отличие от кода автора упомянутого вами вопроса, мой код работает и проходит все проверки кроме лимита времени выполнения.

Этот вопрос похож на: Задача о перемещении между островами. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Подадим на вход вашей программы один материк из n = 50000 островов. Программа создаст полный граф, в котором будет больше миллиарда рёбер (n(n - 1)/2). Потребуется много времени и много памяти чтобы его заполнить.
Вместо этого каждый материк оформим как звезду: центральный узел материка связан со всеми своими островами. Такая звезда имеет линейную, не квадратичную, сложность. К сожалению, путешествие с острова на остров одного материка потребует двух шагов.
Я не хочу делать полноценного Дейкстру. Так что в цепочку между островами вставим дополнительные узлы. Тогда перемещение между соседними в цепочке островами потребует двух шагов.
Получился двудольный граф: в первой доле реальные острова, во второй доле дополнительные узлы в цепочке и материки. Любой путь между реальными островами в таком графе будет иметь чётную длину. Деля её пополам получим ответ к задаче.
Граф индексируется целыми числами. Реальный остров i получает индекс 2i в графе, индексы между реальными островами занимают дополнительные узлы. Индексы материков последовательные, начиная с 2n - 1, где n количество реальных островов.
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Journey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> islands = new ArrayList<>();
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            islands.add(s.nextInt());
        }

        final int n = islands.size();

        List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; ++j) {
            graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 2; ++j) {
            connect(graph, j, j + 1);
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> continents = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int c = islands.get(i);
            if (!continents.containsKey(c)) {
                continents.put(c, graph.size());
                graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            connect(graph, 2 * i, continents.get(c));
        }

        int distance[] = new int[graph.size()];
        Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

        queue.add(0);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            int j = queue.remove();
            if (j == 2 * n - 2) {
                break;
            }
            for (int k : graph.get(j)) {
                if (distance[k] == 0) {
                    distance[k] = distance[j] + 1;
                    queue.add(k);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(distance[2 * n - 2] / 2);
    }

    private static void connect(List<List<Integer>> graph, int i, int j) {
        graph.get(i).add(j);
        graph.get(j).add(i);
    }
}


$ javac Journey.java

$ echo 4 6 3 3 6 | java Journey
2

$ echo 31  -6  -6  21 31 8  8  8  5 21 | java Journey
3

$ echo 7 6 1 6 1 6 1 7 | java Journey
1

$ time seq -s' ' 1 50000 | java Journey
49999

real  0m0.239s
user  0m0.636s
sys   0m0.032s

$ time python -c "print(*[1] * 50000)" | java Journey
1

real  0m0.219s
user  0m0.632s
sys   0m0.044s



Вы гений! Спасибо вам большое!
